# What would be appropriate output pixel size while converting contours into DEM/DTM?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, cartography

I have contours having 10 meter (32.8 feet approximately) interval. Now, I am using these contours to Interpolate a hydrologically correct raster surface in a bid to calculate slope and other topographic attributes. The 'Topo to Raster' tool available in ArcGIS will be utilized to do so.

Keeping in view of my 10 meters contour interval, what would be optimal output cell size should I choose to get maximum from these contours.

Is there any rule of thumb to get pixel size based on the interval of contours?

Comment: 10 m cell size, this is what I use anyway

Comment: Please see the related question at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8900 for some guidance.  For another analysis that might have some bearing on your question, visit http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/55507.  There can be no universal rule of thumb due to variations in the analytical objectives, including the scale at which the surface needs to be "hydrologically correct" and the implications for interpolation error in the subsequent use of that surface.

Comment: Thank you for guidance, keeping in view my 10,000 scale and 10 meters contour interval, I have assigned pixel size of 10 meters as an output resolution. I will go through these links to ascertain pros and cons.